# Why does the location of where I edit the length of my form prevent me from entering information in the form?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with several vertical form fields. I'd like to edit this to make a series of horizontal and vertical form fields. As per the bootstrap API (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) you can create a class with something like col-xs-4 to edit the length of the form fields and if you choose to make it so that the form can be spaced horizontally as well. When I attempt to space some of the fields horizontally I can't type in the fields. I've tried raising them to the top using CSS Z-index but that doesn't seem to work.

My code with two vertical input fields that work:

```css
    .form{
      z-index: 12;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="questions" class="form col-xs-4" name="form" ng-submit="signUp()" novalidate>
    
    
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': form.total.$valid && submitted,
                                                    'has-error': form.total.$invalid && submitted }">
                    <label>Business Name</label>
    
                    <input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" ng-model="user.businessname"
                           required/>
                </div>
            
    
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': form.total.$valid && submitted,
                                                    'has-error': form.total.$invalid && submitted }">
                    <label>Email</label>
    
                    <input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email"
                       required/>
                </div>
          </form>
      </div>
```

My code with two horizontal input fields that look right but I cannot type into them; you can see my CSS with Z-index included in this one:

```css
.form{
      z-index: 12;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form id="questions" class="form" name="form" ng-submit="signUp()" novalidate>

         <div class=  "col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': form.total.$valid && submitted,
                                                'has-error': form.total.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Business Name</label>

                <input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" ng-model="user.businessname"
                       required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=  "col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': form.total.$valid && submitted,
                                                'has-error': form.total.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Email</label>

                <input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email"
                   required/>
            </div>
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Note: Tried CSS with both .form and .form-group...

Comment: When I run your code in snipets (currently waiting on the peer review on the edit) I can type in the inputs regardless of the layout.  There seems to be something outside of the code you've included causes the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me share a bigger piece of code then:

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I add/edit the code submitted or do I need to start a whole new question?

Comment: You can edit it in your post (between the snippet tags) or simply redo the snippets (don't forget to include the bootstrap references).  There's a button in the editor for snippet creation.

Comment: I messed up this question big time. After several hours of tinkering and review, Bootstrap is very particular about things and I needed to have <form class="form-inline" to make it work. I'm not sure where the error outside the code sample was but I know that I got it to work once I changed this.

Comment: Someone else may run into the same problem and need the same solution. You should add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is very particular so

will create the error mentioned above.